# Config for devMode not showing when true

Tags: config, multi-environment

I am using .env to set environment to local:

```
# .ENV The environment Craft is currently running in ('dev', 'staging', 
'production', etc.)
 CRAFTENV_CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT="local"
```

My general config looks like:

```
 // Dev environment settings
'local' => [
    'devMode' => true,

    // Base site URL
    'siteUrl' => getenv('CRAFTENV_BASE_URL')

],
```

My staging site is :

```
 // Staging environment settings
'staging' => [
    // Base site URL
    'siteUrl' => getenv('CRAFTENV_BASE_URL'),

    // Dev Mode (see https://craftcms.com/support/dev-mode)
    'devMode' => true,

    'baseUrl'  => getenv('CRAFTENV_BASE_URL'),
    'basePath' => getenv('CRAFTENV_BASE_PATH'),
    'aliases' => [
        '@assetBaseUrl' => getenv('ASSET_BASE_URL'),
        '@assetBasePath' => getenv('ASSET_BASE_PATH'),
        '@baseUrl' => getenv('CRAFTENV_BASE_URL'),
        '@basePath' => getenv('CRAFTENV_BASE_PATH')
    ],
    // Custom site-specific config settings
    'custom' => [
        'craftEnv' => getenv('CRAFTENV_CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT'),
        'staticAssetsVersion' => 1,
    ]
],
```

Why wont my local site show the dev mode settings in CP ?

Comment: Are you using .env or are you using .env.php? If the former, you want the constant to be: `ENVIRONMENT="local"`

Comment: .env for sure (was using env.php but had some issues). Have disabled SEOmatic and other plugins but it looks like it never reads .env. I just had it working if devMode is tru in global so its missing my 'local' config section..

Comment: ENVIRONMENT="local" solved it - ThankYou!

Comment: @joomkit Can you add your solution as an official answer in case it ends up helping someone in the future?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was ENVIRONMENT="local" in .env
via andrew.welch